# Update Kubernetes Secret in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-ecr

I'm using an **ECR private repo** to pull my docker image for my **Kubernetes cluster** to run. To achieve this, ECR authorisation token is required.

I've used a Terraform module to get this authorisation token as the below;

```
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}
```

I have then injected this token into my **kubernetes secrete** in order to **authenticate and login** to ECR and pull the image:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "docker" {
  metadata {
    name      = "docker-cfg"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.data-layer.metadata.0.name
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = jsonencode({
      auths = {
        "${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint}" = {
          auth = "${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.authorization_token}"
        }
      }
    })
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}
```

This secret is later on **used in the pod**, as the **imagePullSecret** like the below;

```
spec {

    image_pull_secrets {
      name = "docker-cfg"
    }

    container {
      image             = "ECR REPO FQDN"
      name              = "Repo name"
      image_pull_policy = "Always"


      port {
        container_port = 4000
      }
    }
}
```

This is cool and **everything works fine**, however the ECR token expires after 12 hours, how can I **update this token** in my cluster through Terraform? I'm aware of [local_exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) and the [Kubernetes Cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), but what's the cleanest way to achieve this in Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no way to revoke individual ECR authorization tokens in AWS (As of today). May be we can take help of Amazon Secure Token Services (STS), if that helps your usecase. Please find below reference links for more details

Reference links :

AWS STS  : [Aws secure token service](https://www.learnaws.org/2022/02/05/aws-cli-assume-role/)

Github issue link : [aws ecr token expiry issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/936)

terraform + aws sts : [AWS sts in terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Invicton-Labs/sts-role-assumption/aws/latest?tab=inputs)